# How to include client's IP address in the ASP.NET Core logging with log4net?

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there any message template or other technique available to capture the client's IP address and print that in each log using log4net?

At this moment, I have the following conversion pattern for log4net

```
 <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
```

So, I am not sure, if I simply add a placeholder for getting the IP address, Will log4bet magically know the client's IP address and print that?

OR do I need to configure my ASP.Net Core 3.1 website as well?

This is my current "CreateHostBuilder method.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddLog4Net();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

So, do I also need to make some changes to this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally, I found the solution. So, I am answering my own question.

I have created a middleware snippet like this:

```
    app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
    {
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ipAddress"] =
                                          httpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress;

         await next();
    });
```

Then, I have placed the middleware snippet within the Configure method in Startup.cs file as shown below.

[image]

Then, in my log4net config file, I added  **%property{ipAddress}** in the conversion pattern value.

[image]

Then, I see the IP address logged in the log file. I Hope, this solution will help someone who needs it.